# XslLink doesn't work

Tags: web-part, xslt, xslt-list-view-web-part

I create a webpart on my page. And I give style to the webpart with xslt file. And I'm linked this xslt file in my page. But xslt file doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
<WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart runat="server" ViewFlag="" ViewSelectorFetchAsync="False" InplaceSearchEnabled="False" ServerRender="False" ClientRender="True" InitialAsyncDataFetch="False" WebId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" IsClientRender="False" GhostedXslLink="main.xsl" NoDefaultStyle="" ViewGuid="{DD69E458-43FD-474F-99CA-B74A5CD6F2E7}" EnableOriginalValue="False" ViewContentTypeId="" ListUrl="" ListDisplayName="" ListName="{FB95D7AA-8724-4046-9722-50F92A0C54D6}" ListId="fb95d7aa-8724-4046-9722-50f92a0c54d6" PageSize="-1" UseSQLDataSourcePaging="True" DataSourceID="" ShowWithSampleData="False" AsyncRefresh="False" ManualRefresh="False" AutoRefresh="False" AutoRefreshInterval="60" Title="bt_haberduyuru" FrameType="Default" SuppressWebPartChrome="False" Description="" IsIncluded="True" ZoneID="wpz" PartOrder="2" FrameState="Normal" AllowRemove="True" AllowZoneChange="True" AllowMinimize="True" AllowConnect="True" AllowEdit="True" AllowHide="True" IsVisible="True" CatalogIconImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/itann.png?rev=23" TitleUrl="/Lists/bt_haberduyuru" DetailLink="/Lists/bt_haberduyuru" HelpLink="" HelpMode="Modeless" Dir="Default" PartImageSmall="" MissingAssembly="Cannot import this Web Part." PartImageLarge="/_layouts/15/images/itann.png?rev=23" IsIncludedFilter="" ExportControlledProperties="False" ConnectionID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" ID="g_c857a4e0_f9e6_4134_b434_32c72d3f955a" __MarkupType="vsattributemarkup" __WebPartId="{DD69E458-43FD-474F-99CA-B74A5CD6F2E7}" __AllowXSLTEditing="true" __designer:CustomXsl="fldtypes_Ratings.xsl" WebPart="true" Height="" Width=""><ParameterBindings>
  <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_sortdir" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
            <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_sortfield" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
            <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_startposition" Location="Postback" DefaultValue=""/>
            <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_firstrow" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
            <ParameterBinding Name="OpenMenuKeyAccessible" Location="Resource(wss,OpenMenuKeyAccessible)" />
            <ParameterBinding Name="open_menu" Location="Resource(wss,open_menu)" />
            <ParameterBinding Name="select_deselect_all" Location="Resource(wss,select_deselect_all)" />
            <ParameterBinding Name="idPresEnabled" Location="Resource(wss,idPresEnabled)" /><ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" /><ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_DEFAULT)" /></ParameterBindings>
<DataFields>
</DataFields>
<XslLink>Style Library/LinkListStyle/bt_main/bt_haberler.xslt</XslLink>
     <XmlDefinition><View Name="{DD69E458-43FD-474F-99CA-B74A5CD6F2E7}" MobileView="TRUE" Type="HTML" Hidden="TRUE" DisplayName="" Url="/SitePages/Ahnet.aspx" Level="255" BaseViewID="1" ContentTypeID="0x" ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/announce.png?rev=23" ><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="Modified" Ascending="FALSE"/></OrderBy></Query><ViewFields><FieldRef Name="LinkTitle"/><FieldRef Name="Created"/></ViewFields><RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit><Aggregations Value="Off"/><JSLink>clienttemplates.js</JSLink><XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink><Toolbar Type="Standard"/></View></XmlDefinition>
</WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart>
```

And this my xslt code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl msxsl ddwrt" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal">


<xsl:output method='html' indent='yes'/>

            <xsl:template match='dsQueryResponse' xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" ddwrt:ghost="" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls">




<ul class="list-group bt-nav-margin bt-back">
<xsl:apply-templates select='Rows/Row'/>
</ul>
<!--<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="tumu pull-right"><a href="#">Tüm Duyuruları Görüntüle &nbsp;&nbsp; <span> 
<img src="/../../_styles/bt_master/assets/img/arrow.png" height="10" width="13" alt=""/></span></a></div>-->



</xsl:template>



<xsl:template match='Row'>
<li class="list-group-item"><a href="/Lists/bt_haberduyuru/DispForm.aspx?ID={string(@ID)}" >
<strong>
<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate(string($thisNode/@Created),1036,1)" />
</strong>
<xsl:value-of select="@Body"/></a></li>      
</xsl:template>





</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Could you help me?

Thanks.

**Edited**

```
</ParameterBindings>
<Xsl>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl msxsl ddwrt" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal">                                                                              
<xsl:output method='html' indent='yes'/>
<xsl:template match='dsQueryResponse' xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" ddwrt:ghost="" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls">
      <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates></xsl:apply-templates>
      </ul>
  </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Row">
      <li> 
         <xsl:value-of select="@Body"/>      </li>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet></Xsl>
<DataFields>
</DataFields>
```

When I try the above code, I get this error message in the part of this web part:

> Web Part Error: Type
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.XsltListViewWebPart' does not have
>   a public property named 'stylesheet'. Correlation ID:
>   24d0859c-e95c-e0ac-af18-ebc527102d2a

Comment: You are specifying relative path Style Library/LinkListStyle/bt_main/bt_haberler.xslt, is that correct?

Comment: yes, it's true. I'm specifying path for my xslt file

Comment: @VadimGremyachev I edited my question. I get a new error. But I have stylesheet. What should I do?